# Making a search script loop through an array instead of a text entry value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search

```
$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblCocktail WHERE Ingredients LIKE '%$term%'");
```

This is part of the code I am using to take the value from a text entry box and search my database. However I want to change it so that instead of **%$term%** It loops through an array, for the ability to search for multiple selected terms.

Any help is appreciated

-Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct the search expression by looping through the array.

```
$search = '';
foreach ($_POST['term'] as $term) {
    $search .= " OR '$term'";
}
$search = preg_replace('/^ OR/', '', $search); // remove first OR

// Ingredients LIKE $search
```

But beware you should be using prepared statements rather than having expressions like these to avoid SQL injection.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MySQL's MATCH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) functionality to accomplish this most effectively. You'll want to put a fulltext index on the column and then you can use sophisticated searches like:

```
SELECT * FROM tblCocktail WHERE MATCH (Ingredients) AGAINST ('%$Term1%', '%$Term2$');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding complex logic and query building, add a `FULLTEXT` attribute to the table and do a full text search for it:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblCocktail` (
 `id`          INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Ingredients` VARCHAR(255)
  ...
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)),
 FULLTEXT(`Ingredients`)
ENGINE = MyISAM;

...

 $terms = implode($term_array);  // todo: protect against injection here too
 $query = "SELECT *
           FROM `tblCocktail`
           WHERE MATCH(`Ingredients`) AGAINST ('$terms')";
```